# Ubuntu 20.04 is not updating due installedpackages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Iam using Ubuntu 20.04,when I tried to update the following error showing;Error opening the cache (E:Read error-read(5:Input/output error),E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)This usually means thatyour installed packages have unmet dependencies.    ......

Comment: Look up the meaning of `Input/output error`

Answer (score 0):

Your package list is corrupted. Remove the list with the command

`sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/`

Recreate it by the command

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

Followingly update and upgrade the package with the commands

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```