# Error: opening temporary files

Tags: apt, package-management

Error: opening temporary files (E: can not open / var / lib / apt / lists / by.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease fopen (13: Permission denied), E: The package lists or status file could not  be parsed or opened.) "

HOW TO CLEAR THE ERROR?

[Ubuntu 20.04 is not updating due installedpackages have unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351097/ubuntu-20-04-is-not-updating-due-installedpackages-have-unmet-dependencies) ON THE LINK DID, DO NOT HELP

Comment: What command or what action gives you this error message?

Comment: That particular file ought to be owned by root, so it can only be opened by a root-owned process, such as a `sudo` command.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and add its output to the question.